# Calcular rotas, distancia e tempo no OpenStreetMap

Tags: javascript, html, maps, rotas

Preciso de uma API que calcula rotas entre Origem/Destino e que forneça a **distância e o tempo** de percurso para uma matriz de origens e destinos utilizando o **OpenStreetMap**.

Que funcione como a API Directions e Distance Matrix do Google Maps e que seja com com um preço viável a varias solicitações, saberiam de alguma?

Comment: Já estou utilizando o OpenStreetMap, preciso de APIs que resolvam o problema dos calculos

Comment: @rLinhares ele esta pedindo bem mais do que uma sugestão, esta pedindo como usar a API pra calcular as distancias, na outra pergunta não tem nada sobre isto, portanto não cobre a pergunta inteiramente.